# Change picturebox image inside form1 from test.cs

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I am trying to update picture box image inside "form1" from another cs file
my code inside test.cs

```
slot_13.modifier = public;
```

and inside form1 i wrote this also

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

test.cs

```
inventory_Viewer.viewer x = new inventory_Viewer.viewer();
x.slot_13.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Axmed\Google Drive\C# Source Codes\inventory Viewer\inventory Viewer\bin\Release\icon\icon_default.png");
```

But it doesn't work
If i used this line inside "form1"

```
x.slot_13.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Axmed\Google Drive\C# Source Codes\inventory Viewer\inventory Viewer\bin\Release\icon\icon_default.png");
```

image gets changed

Comment: Is the form you're trying to change `inventory_Viewer.viewer`, and is it already visible? Then you shouldn't `new` one, but pass a reference. Try searching. Why doesn't it work? What _does_ happen?

Comment: the form is already visible and how to pass the reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code misses a lot of context, so I'm going to do a few assumptions. Given a MainForm that shows the InventoryViewerForm and also wants to change the image on the InventoryViewerForm, you could hold a reference to the second form like this:

```
// Your inventory_Viewer.viewer
public partial class InventoryViewerForm
{
    public InventoryViewerForm()
    {
    }
}

// The form from which to show the viewer. 
public partial class MainForm
{
    private readonly InventoryViewerForm _inventoryViewerForm;

    public MainForm()
    {
        _inventoryViewerForm = new InventoryViewerForm();
    }

    private void ShowInventoryViewerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _inventoryViewerForm.Show();
    }

    private void ChangeImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Dispose the previously loaded image.
        if (_inventoryViewerForm.Image != null)
        {
            _inventoryViewerForm.Image.Dispose();
        }

        _inventoryViewerForm.Image = Image.FromFile("NewImage.png");
    }
}
```

But this is bad design altogether. You don't want to tightly couple your forms like this, and you want to leverage the data binding of WinForms and the events of .NET for this. In order to properly implement that, you'll need to show more code.